# apache2 UserDir Deny to everyone exept me

Tags: apache-2.2, hosting, virtualhost, web

I have set up a Debain 6 VPS for PHP web developpement / personal hosting and have a quick question :

I want to host production code in : /var/www/site.com, and developpement code in /home/username/public_html/site

I have set up userdir.conf (Default setup I think) :

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir public_html
    UserDir disabled root

    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
            AllowOverride All
            Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Limit>
            <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
                    Order deny,allow
                    Deny from all
            </LimitExcept>
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

I can access both codebases via : www.site.com and www.site.com/~username/site respectively

My question Is : What is the best way restrict www.site.com/~username/site (My project in developpement state) to the outside world ?  ( .htaccess, virtualhost setup, other )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you connect to the VPS from a fixed IP address then changing the `Allow from all` to `Allow from IP.AD.RE.SS` is quick and easy. If you don't then you could set up [basic authentication](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html) using a .htaccess file. Put something like

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName Private
Authuserfile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

In a public_html/.htaccess file.

Initialise the .htpasswd file

```
htpasswd -c /path/to/.htpasswd Purplefish32
New password: mypassword
Re-type new password: mypassword
Adding password for user Purplefish32
```

Then ensure that your main apache configuration has a suitable [allowoverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive e.g. `AllowOverride AuthConfig`. If required restart apache and now you should be asked to provide a password to access the contents of your development files.

Comment: I went with : Allow from IP.AD.RE.SS - Works perfectly, Thanks

Comment: Just be aware that if your ip.ad.re.ss is dynamic you will have to edit the server config when it changes.